# How to get the names of the TIF images from a folder and input it names in a database? in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm about to get the names of the images that came from one folder and input its names in a database. can someone help? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collect all tif-images of a folder with `Directory.EnumerateFile`/`GetFiles`:

```
IEnumerable<string> tifs = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.tif");
foreach(string file in tifs)
{
    string imageName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file);
    // insert into database
}
```

If you want the name without extension use `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`.

VB.NET version:

```
Dim tifs = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.tif")
For Each file As String In tifs
    Dim imageName As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file)
    ' insert into DB ...'
Next
```

Comment: (file) = then what should be the value i will be inputted in here?

Comment: ow, i will try first

Comment: @Jham: no, because you haven't mentioned what doesn't work.

Comment: @Jham: added the VB.NET version

Comment: "Directory.EnumerateFiles" this, doesn't ork

Comment: i only used vb.net 2005

Comment: @Jham: then you have to use `Directory.GetFiles`

Comment: i've tried to use it but it multiplied by how many images the folder have.
or simply (folder:50 images) 50x50

Comment: @Jham: that must be caused by your code which i don't know. Maybe a loop in a loop.

Comment: i've checked the loop i coded and i get it now, thanks

Comment: Hi @Tim. I'm about to create a question but i got my limit. Can you help me to count the rows inside the database?

Comment: @Jham: sure: `SELECT COUNT(*) AS CountRows FROM dbo.TableName`

Comment: it this valid on vb.net? sorry, just a beginner.

Comment: @Jham: that's SQL, you have asked a database question which is usually sql.

Comment: ow, how about counting that thing on vb.net? is that possible?

Comment: @Jham: i don't understand the requirement. You can use ADO.NET to execute a query on your database. But your question is far too broad currently. You could load all into a `DataTable`(f.e. `SqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable)`) and then use `table.Rows.Count` to get the row count. But if you are interested only in the row-count and not in the data itself it would be better to use `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar` where it's `CommandText` is `SELECT COUNT(*)FROM table`

Comment: just a row count. what would be the perfect codes on this? sorry, not understand what to do.

Comment: You haven't even mentioned the rdbms(database) that you're using.

Comment: let's name it a DB1, sorry my database made was in auto increment and in format as "0000000.##"

Comment: @Jham: an rdbms is for example:  `MS SQL-Server` or `Oracle` or `MySql`.

Comment: isn't it possible to just use on vb.net? anyway i am using adox.catalog and an oledb for creating databases. is any possible way to count the rows inside of those database?

Comment: @Jham: so you're trying to get the row count of a table in MS Access?

Comment: and also how about fitting the image in picturebox? so that when it zoom in it doesn't affect the entire form?

Comment: @Jham: sorry, that's really too broad and too much to be answered in comments. Ask a real question if you can. And try to find some tutorials on ADO.NET.

Comment: Hi Tim? Can you help me to zoom in and out a picture but when it zoomed it totally can see clear the small letters inside the image

Comment: You have to ask a real question, I'm sure someone can help you. I'm in holidays ;)

Comment: oww, okay. huhu how about zoom in and out using mouse wheel? huhu I can't post a question due to reaching the limit. :'(

Comment: Hi Tim, can you help me with something?

Comment: can you help me zoom in an image? using mousehwheel? the exact image in picturebox. cause everytime i zoom the picturebox it can't help to crop the image of it. because it only crop the original image but not the zoom in image. can you help me pls? :'(

Comment: Private Sub ImageCropping_MouseWheel(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseWheel
    If e.Delta <> 0 Then
            If e.Delta <= 0 Then
                If PictureBox1.Width < 500 Then Exit Sub

            Else
                If PictureBox1.Width > 5000 Then Exit Sub
            End If

            PictureBox1.Width += CInt(PictureBox1.Width * e.Delta / 1000)
            PictureBox1.Height += CInt(PictureBox1.Height * e.Delta / 1000)

        End If

 End Sub

the above code was the code i've been using right now

Comment: Hi Tim, could you please give me a sample of zooming using mousewheel and cropping using button. Please I need it badly. :'( help me pls! :'(